# How to setup VMWare Player on dual-homed (2 NICs) host?

Tags: linux, vmware-player

Host OS is Vista, Guest OS is Linux.

The host has 2 NICs: one LAN, one WAN.

Currently the guest only sees the LAN.

How can I get the guest OS to directly see and access both the LAN and WAN NICs?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried editing the vmx file and adding ethernet1 entries (in addition to the already existing ethernet0's), the result was that the Guest OS ended up with two NICs, unfortunately both get bridged on to the LAN NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vmnetcfg didn't work in my situation. Actual solution was to upgrade to VMWare Player 3.0 (from 2.5) where the NICs can be managed in the VMware GUI itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the vmware player directory is a little app called vmnetcfg. Run that and you can determine which host interface will be used -- and how. From there you can set up both for bridging if so desired.

Since you're on Vista, be sure to run it as admin (right-click, run as...)